# Alignment issues in Android XML

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I want to add backbutton and a divider on my header and i have already used linear layout is there any way to do this without major changes in code ? Below is screenshot and code :

BackButton and Divider code :

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back"/>

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdivider"
            android:layout_width="2dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
            android:background="#85929B" 
            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
            android:paddingTop="15dip" />
```

Full Code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e7ebee"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="452dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        BACK BUTTON
        DIVIDER


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#0a2436"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" >
        </ImageView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" />

        <!--  android:divider="@color/listDivider" -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
     >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#092435"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#4982AE"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Activity"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            android:background="#85929B" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Support"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

         <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            android:background="#85929B" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Messages"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code for divider

Horizontal line

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/view"
   android:background="#FF4500"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="2dp"     
   android:layout_below="@+id/listview_id" />
```

vertical line

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/view"
   android:background="#FF4500"
   android:layout_width="2dp"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"     />
```

YOUR xml change like this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#e7ebee"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backdivider"
        android:layout_width="2dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
        android:background="#85929B"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="452dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#0a2436"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" >
    </ImageView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingTop="0dip" />

    <!-- android:divider="@color/listDivider" -->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#4982AE"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Activity"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                android:background="#85929B" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Support"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                android:background="#85929B" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Messages"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Code I already have for divider. My only concern is how to integrate them with Layout i have ??

Comment: Thanks it didn't work completely but worked to me to an certain extent that i can handle it...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<View android:layout_width="2dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#0a2436"/>
```

Its not the best solution, but you better for you as you are saying that you do not want much modification in code.